# Use webapp to get iPhone image flash status

Tags: javascript, ios, image, web-applications, ios-camera

I am writing a web app that allows iphone users to upload images. Based on some research it looks like iphones will strip EXIF data before uploading images. Is there some way I can extract flash status before iphone uploads the image?

relevant post:
https://www.flickr.com/help/forum/en-us/72157700799502582/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, by flash I mean whether image was taken with Flash on